# When I leave the Username and Password blank it says guest was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

```
:lockdown
cls
echo Please Enter Your Username and Password to Play Game.
echo.
set /p user=Username: 
set /p word=Password: 
if /i %user% EQU guest goto main
if /i %user% EQU ryan (if /i %word% EQU %echo2% goto main)
if /i %user% EQU Ryan (if /i %word% EQU %echo2% goto main)
if /i %user% EQU tanner (if /i %word% EQU tanner goto main1)
if /i %user% EQU Tanner (if /i %word% EQU Tanner goto main1)
if /i %user% EQU austin (if /i %word% EQU austin goto main)
if /i %user% EQU Austin (if /i %word% EQU Austin goto main)
if /i %user% EQU duncan (if /i %word% EQU duncan goto main)
if /i %user% EQU Duncan (if /i %word% EQU Duncan goto main)
```

Comment: Please format the code, otherwise no one will read this.

Comment: What is the 'iOS' tag for? Is this happening in an iOS app? Please provide further information.
@Luka I edited and formatted the code for them.

Comment: I have removed the tags that were there just to attract views. If they were appropriate after all, elaborate why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set double quotes in every `if` line:

```
 if /i "%user%" EQU "guest" goto main
```